# Echarts - get processed data

Tags: echarts

Is there any possibility to obtain [echarts](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/index.html) processed series data? I'm trying to create a summary component which should display the sum of currently displayed (visible - based on dataZoom start/end) series data.

I cannot find solution/property in the echarts documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found the solution to this one already?

Comment: couldn't paste formatted code here so answer is below - example for serie passed to function

Answer (score -1):

```
getSummaryValue: function(serie) {
  const start = this.start || (serie.data.slice(0, 1)[0] || [])[0]
  const end = this.end || (serie.data.slice(-1)[0] || [])[0]
  const processedYData = _filter(serie.data, data => {
    return data[0] >= start && data[0] <= end
  })
  let values = processedYData.map(item => parseFloat(item[1] || 0))

  return formatter(_sum(values), serie.unit)
}
```

Comment: but where did you attach this, did you attached it as callback?